# Javascript: Trigger event before a lazily loaded image gets requested by the browser

Tags: javascript, image, lazy-loading

I like to display lazy loaded images in my web-app using `loading="lazy"`. The problem I have is that the client needs to have a time limited token to request images from the server.

If an image scrolls onto the viewport, the client needs to request a token and with this token the client can request the image. For doing so, I need some kind of event or trigger to be fired *before* the lazy loaded image is requested by the browser.
I can not send the token with the first page hit or somewhere inbetween because I do not know how long the user is visiting other parts of the app before the images get visible. The time varies between some seconds and hours.

`<img onload="doStuff()" />` gets fired *after* the image has been loaded. This is too late. I need something *before* the image is requested.

I'm not bounded to use images or `loading="lazy"` to resolve this issue. Any workaround is also welcome.

Comment: Use that as the trigger to set the url to "loading.jpg" when you get the token change the url to the correct image (`img.src=good_image`)

Comment: You should have been able to handle a [loadstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onloadstart) event, except that Chrome doesn't support it on <img>, for whatever reasons... So you're left with either a placeholder image as @Shanimal proposes (this could be a single pixel gif btw), but you may face some issues with cache (not sure what cache strategy you're aiming for if the users need a token), or you'd have to re-implement the lazy-loading yourself, using an IntersectionObserver.

Comment: @Shanimal if you need a working snippet for your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/ytjgavn3/